# Name of this identity? inner product, divergence, gradient

Tags: vector-analysis

Let
$f$ be a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$

$M$ be a `nice` proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

$C$ is the boundary of $M$

Define the inner product in scalar field, $u, v: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation}
\langle u, v \rangle = \int_M uv
\end{equation}

What is the name of the identity below?
\begin{equation}
\langle u, \nabla \cdot \mathbf{f} \rangle = \oint_C u \mathbf{f} - \int_M \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{f}
\end{equation}
where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product, $\nabla$ denotes gradient operator, $\nabla \cdot$ denotes divergence operator

Comment: What you write in how you use variables makes little sense. $u,v$ are vector-valued functions? $f$ is a scalar-valued function? Then perchance did you mean $⟨u,∇f⟩=\oint_C uf\,dn-\int_M f∇⋅u\,dvol$? I would think this case of partial integration goes under "Green's theorem"? Or perhaps the Gauss theorem in combination with the product rule $∇⋅(fu)=(∇f)·u+f(∇⋅u)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment of Lutz Lehmann,

Product rule:
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot (u \mathbf{f}) = \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{f} + u \nabla \cdot \mathbf{f}
\end{equation}

Integrate both side over $M$

\begin{equation}
\int_M \nabla \cdot (u \mathbf{f}) = \int_M \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{f} + \langle u, \nabla \cdot f \rangle
\end{equation}

Gauss's Theorem / Divergence Theorem

\begin{equation}
\int_M \nabla \cdot \mathbf{g} = \oint_C \mathbf{g}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{g} = u \mathbf{f}$

**References:**

[1] [https://services.math.duke.edu/~leili/teaching/duke/math212s16/lectures/lec17.pdf](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Eleili/teaching/duke/math212s16/lectures/lec17.pdf)